# Extracting data using fieldnames

Tags: python, csv

I have parsed and extracted lines and field names from a CSV data file using:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('Sourcefile.txt','rt'), delimiter = '\t')
fn = reader.fieldnames
```

How do I access the parsed data in any line using the fieldname? For example fieldnames could be `AA`, `BB`, `CC`, `DD`. How do obtain the value for `DD` in line 5, or `AA` in line 3?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can just skip around lines, but you could just read `x-1` lines and ignore the result before reading line `x` and doing something

Comment: And is `rt` a typo? I think it should be `rb` for read-binary

Answer (score 2):

As long as the file is not too big just convert the reader into a list:

```
data = list(reader)
```

Now access the column `AA` in row 1:

```
data[0]['AA']
```

or column for field name 3 in row 3:

```
data[2][fn[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to store all of the data in your file into a container. An alternative to the other answer is to use a pandas dataframe:

```
>>import pandas as pd
>>from io import StringIO  # just to make a fake in memory file
>>s = StringIO('AA\tBB\tCC\tDD\n1\t2\t3\t4\n11\t12\t13\t14\n') # fake data
>>data = pd.read_table(s)
>>data.loc[0,'AA']  # access row 0 (the first row) and column AA
1
```

Edit: This does use a different package not included with the standard library, but I often find it easier to use pandas than csv when I am constantly reading and manipulating csv files.